# Invalid id token in spring when aws cognito response

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have a microservice in spring boot with login oauth2 and cognito. The login service works fine, but when spring boot gets the answer, it shows invalid_id_token. I don't know why.
I configured the cognito provider in AWS, and this is my application.properties:

```
server.port=8000
app.url=http://localhost:${server.port}
cognito.rooturl=https://XXXX.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.provider=cognito
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=XXXXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-secret=XXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-name=test-cognito-2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.redirect-uri=${app.url}/login/oauth2/code/cognito


spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.authorization-uri=${cognito.rooturl}/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.token-uri=${cognito.rooturl}/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.jwk-set-uri=https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-XXXXXX/.well-known/jwks.json
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.user-info-uri=${cognito.rooturl}/oauth2/userInfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.user-name-attribute=username

#Database
spring.datasource.name=test_ms
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

My Solution:

I've configured a success url login:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
     http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/logout")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/m1/entry");
     }
 }
```

Then We create pages html using thymeleaf:

```
@PostMapping("/m1/entry")
@ResponseBody
public  String urlTestEntry() {
        return "succes";
}
```

Html pages:

[image: Pages created]

I tested again and It's works!!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I believe that's because of lack of some @Configuration. In this guide you can find a step-by-step setup for the entire process of integrating Spring + Security + Cognito: https://gofore.com/en/spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks a lot. However  I found the solution. This was happend because when I get the response I didn't redirect to html page.

Comment: Could you please tell us how did you manage it? (Maybe putting the solution as the answer to this thread) Obrigado!

Comment: Hahahahahaha sure @RaffaelBecharaRameh